# how to reset navigation addListener when a state is changed

Tags: react-native

I want to reset navigation addListener when state is changed but It's not working

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const {page, pageIdx, tab} = pageInfo

    const remove = navigation.addListener('state', ({data:{state:{routes, index}}}) => {
      if(routes[index].name === name){
        if(pageIdx)
          getMatchItem(`usr/goods/match/buy/history/${tab}/${page}`)
        else
          getItem(`usr/goods/auction/bid/${tab}/${page}`)
        }
      return () => remove()
      })
  }, [pageInfo])
```

so I tried to return remove function when state is changed but It couldn't work

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```js
const [stateChanged, setStateChaged] = useState(false)
const [listener, setListener] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  if(stateChanged && listener) {
    listener()
    setListener(null)
  }
}, [stateChanged])

useEffect(() => {
    const {page, pageIdx, tab} = pageInfo

    const remove = navigation.addListener('state', ({data: {state: {routes, index}}}) => {
        if (routes[index].name === name) {
            if (pageIdx)
                getMatchItem(`usr/goods/match/buy/history/${tab}/${page}`)
            else
                getItem(`usr/goods/auction/bid/${tab}/${page}`)
            setStateChaged(true)
        }
    })

    setListener(remove)
}, [pageInfo])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me but It's same It dosen't work neither....

Comment: @YoungsungChoi din't get your question first time, please check my updated answer